# Handling Multiple UITableViews and Insertion/Deletion of cells in those tables

Tags: iphone

I have two table views in a single controller.One is grouped whose frame is (0,0,320,70), other one is plain whose frame is (0,70,320,300).In the grouped tableView, I am adding the cells dynamically and want this plain tableView to shift down, so that the grouped tableView is completely visible. In a similar way,when I remove cells dynamically from grouped tableView, I want the plain tableView to shift Up and adjust according to the new height of grouped tableView.

Help me out with this. Is there any apple provided sample to do such a thing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in interface builder, in your size inspector for the table views, make sure both table views have flexible height set (i.e. the middle vertical up/down arrow in the little grid) and with luck it should just work.

If this doesn't work you could also try in in addition, again in the size inspector in interface builder for each table, make the top table view fixed distance from the top of your containing view and the bottom table view fixed distance from the bottom of your containing view.  (so solid top line, dotted bottom line for the top table view, and solid bottom line, dotted top line for the bottom table view). (still keeping the flexible vertical size setting as well on each - i.e. middle up/down arrow a solid red line).

Don't forget to save you IB changes and rebuild your project before running to test.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing Y-cordinate of your plain table view dynamically (by changing frame coordinates) while adding/deleting the rows in your grouped table view. 
But in this case you need to adjust height of your plain table view as well. else it may go outside of your screen bounds.

For this you can add/subtract width of tableview cell of grouped table view to/from y coordinate of your plain table view. this will give you new y-coordinate value,
similarly calculate new height for your table view and then assign frame as 
(0, new value of y, 320, 300 - new value of y)

Here you need to keep checking values of y coordinate and the height. y should not go beyond height of your device and height of table view should not decrease to 0. otherwise table view will not be visible.